# Convert Switch state to Boolean

Tags: android-studio, boolean, toggleswitch

I'm trying to get the value of a switch (on/off) and tell the data to another class.

I'm not using a switch statement, I have a physical switch which the user can check or uncheck.

I need to get the value of this switch in order to use the data in another class.

Here's what I've tried to use:

```
Switch vibeBlocker = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.hideVibeSwitch);

@Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Boolean vibeHider = Boolean.valueOf(vibeBlocker);
}
```

I receive an error on the line `Boolean vibeHider = Boolean.valueOf(vibeBlocker);`. I'm not sure how to get the value of my switch and convert it to a `boolean`. I know I can use methods like `.toString();` and such, but is there something similar for `boolean`s?

I need to transfer the value of the switch between two classes, and I think this will work. If anyone knows the correct statement here, or a better way to do this, please let me know.

Thanks!

Nathan

Comment: Such a method should be easy to create; but it's hard to say exactly given I don't know what a Switch even is. Say it has the two states Off and On. You could create a function that takes a switch and has the following return: `return switch.isOn();`

Comment: I actually figured this out, I was doing this wrong. I was declaring the switch, but I actually should've just used a `SharedPreferenceManager`. Got everything sorted out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was declaring the Switch and finding it by Id, which didn't work for me. Instead, I had to use a SharedPreferenceManager to put the `boolean` into my bundle:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferencesManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    vibeBlock = mSharedPreferencesManager.getBoolean("vibration_checkbox", false);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myBoolean", vibeBlock);
}
```

That worked to put the `boolean` into the bundle. Here's how I pulled it out in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    hideVibe = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myBoolean");
}
```

I also added this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate();
    (Creation code)
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferencesManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    hideVibe = mSharedPreferencesManager.getBoolean("vibration_checkbox", false);

    if (hideVibe) {
        switchConv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (!hideVibe) {
        switchConv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

And this as well:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferencesManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    hideVibe = mSharedPreferencesManager.getBoolean("vibration_checkbox", false);
    if (hideVibe) {
        switchConv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (!hideVibe) {
        switchConv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

And that did the trick :)